# When upgrading, is there an easy way to remove old default packages?

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I've just upgraded to 11.10 beta using update-manager and all went well.

However, the install process leaves installed default packages from the previous version that I no longer want (gdm, evolution etc.)

I've generated a list of additional packages I have installed via a method similar to

http://www.faqoverflow.com/unix/3595.html

However my list contains lots of packages I installed and do want to keep - is there an easy way to just remove the deprecated default packages?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just run:

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

to remove packages that are no longer needed.
You can also use the "Local or Obsolete" filter in Synaptic at "Status" section.

[image]

Comment: Probably not going to work, as packages are marked as manually installed upon installation, so things like Evolution wouldn't show up there just because dependencies of ubuntu-desktop (or whatever package pulled it in) have changed.

Comment: @htorque: you might be right :P. Some packages though did show up there (as autoremovable) when I upgraded :).