# Remove outdated packages post-upgrade?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS, however due to time restrictions, I had to skip the step where outdated packages are removed. Is there a way for me to easily do this after the whole upgrade process has been completed?

Comment: Can you please try the answer at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60812/when-upgrading-is-there-an-easy-way-to-remove-old-default-packages) (or by doing [this search](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=remove+old+packages)) and see if it helps? If it does, you should flag or delete this one as a duplicate. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this will do it but you could try, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

It should not do any harm.